# Different answer from problem sheet solution, but still correct? PDEs

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

On a problem sheet I have recieved, we are tasked with solving $$xU_x+U_t=\sin(t) $$ Using the method of characteristics, I have found the solution to be $$U(x,t)=f(t-\ln(x))-\cos(t) $$ I have checked this via calculating the relevant partial derivatives and this does indeed satisfy the above PDE. However, the problem sheet's solution says that  $$U(x,t)=f\left( \frac{e^t}{x}\right)-\cos(t)$$ Why are these answers different but both correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that $f$ is an arbitrary function; then you have $f(t-\ln x) = f\left(\ln(e^t/x)\right) = g(e^t/x)$ with $g = f\circ\ln$ another arbitrary function.

Comment: I see. Both solutions are equally valid though, correct? I suppose the solutions are actually equivalent.

Comment: Yes, in the same way you can rename constants of integration with ODEs, but here you have a "function of integration", since we deal with a PDE.